# When I float my div tags inside another div in HTML

Tags: html, css

When I want to float a div inside another, the problem will appear.

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="anotherDiv">
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my style sheet:

```
#main{ background-color:red; padding:20px; }
#anotherDiv{ background-color:blue; }
```

This is my page without float:

[image]

But this is my stile sheet when I add following style:

```
#anotherDiv{ float:left; }
```

[image]

But I want something like this:

[image: www.erfan21.persiangig.com/document/03.png]

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `overflow:auto` to `#main`:

```
#main {
    background-color:red;
    padding:20px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9xp8nkpt/)

The will restore the bahavior of the parent div you seek without any unnecessary HTML elements.

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear the float.
Here is working fiddle:

```css
#main{ background-color:red; padding:20px; }
#anotherDiv{ background-color:blue; }
#anotherDiv{ float:left; }
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="anotherDiv">
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `display: inline-block;` as well.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fpza8fLp/)